# Python: Looping over 2mln lines

Tags: python, loops

I have to loop over large file with 2mln lines, that looks like this

```
P61981  1433G_HUMAN
P61982  1433G_MOUSE
Q5RC20  1433G_PONAB
P61983  1433G_RAT
P68253  1433G_SHEEP
```

Currently I have the following function, that take the every entry in the list, and if the entry in this large file - it took the row with the occurence, but it's slow (~10min). Probably due to the looping scheme, **can you please suggest optimization?**

```
up = "database.txt"

def mplist(somelist):
    newlist = []
    with open(up) as U:
        for row in U:
            for i in somelist:
                if i in row:
                    newlist.append(row)
    return newlist
```

example of the `somelist`

```
somelist = [
    'P68250',
    'P31946',
    'Q4R572',
    'Q9CQV8',
    'A4K2U9',
    'P35213',
    'P68251'
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your `somelist` only contains values found in the first column, then split the line and only test the first value against a `set`, not a `list`:

```
def mplist(somelist):
    someset = set(somelist)
    with open(up) as U:
        return [line for line in U if line.split(None, 1)[0] in someset]
```

Testing against a set is a O(1) constant time operation (independent of the size of the set).

Demo:

```
>>> up = '/tmp/database.txt'
>>> open(up, 'w').write('''\
... P61981  1433G_HUMAN
... P61982  1433G_MOUSE
... Q5RC20  1433G_PONAB
... P61983  1433G_RAT
... P68253  1433G_SHEEP
... ''')
>>> def mplist(somelist):
...     someset = set(somelist)
...     with open(up) as U:
...         return [line for line in U if line.split(None, 1)[0] in someset]
... 
>>> mplist(['P61981', 'Q5RC20'])
['P61981  1433G_HUMAN\n', 'Q5RC20  1433G_PONAB\n']
```

You *may* want to return a generator instead, and only *filter*, not build a list in memory:

```
def mplist(somelist):
    someset = set(somelist)
    with open(up) as U:
        return (line for line in U if line.split(None, 1)[0] in someset)
```

You can loop, but not index this result:

```
for match in mplist(somelist):
    # do something with match
```

and not need to hold all matched entries in memory.

Comment: strangly enough, but it return the empty list

Comment: @millimoose: seeing as the OP only needs to test against the first value of each line, a different test is simpler.

Comment: If the first column is always 6-char long, splitting is not needed. Simply check the first 6 chars. str.split is a costly function for large data.

Comment: Less costly when limiting it to just one split, but yes, a slice would be faster still.